# Large numbers in French

Tags: nombres

Are the following correct?

198,647: cent-quatre-vingt-dix-huit-mille-six-cent-quarante-sept

318,431: trois-cent-dix-huit-mille-quatre-cent-trente-un

2,857,566: deux-millions-huit-cent-cinquante-sept-mille-cinq-cent-soixante-six

Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering if French people dictate their numéro de téléphone two by two?

Comment: @Vim Phones numbers are not considered as regular large numbers but follow specific rules, including the two by two rule you cite.

Comment: They group it by two for local French numbers. If there is a 3-digit prefix (for international codes , or numbers of some other countries), they will dictate it as the whole number (ex: trois cent cinquante-huit). If there is leading "0" in the 2-digit group (eg 06), they will dictate it as "zéro-six".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your only mistake is a missing "*et*" in "*trente-et-un*".

Here is how these numbers are written in the traditional way which is still accepted as correct and the most commonly used:

> *198 647: cent quatre-vingt-dix-huit mille six cent quarante-sept*
>
> *318 431: trois cent dix-huit mille quatre cent trente et un*
>
> *2 857 566: deux millions huit cent cinquante-sept mille cinq cent soixante-six*

Since [the Dec 6, 1990 rectifications](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990), connecting all components of a numeral with dashes is allowed, albeit not mandatory:

> *198 647: cent-quatre-vingt-dix-huit-mille-six-cent-quarante-sept*
>
> *318 431: trois-cent-dix-huit-mille-quatre-cent-trente-et-un*
>
> *2 857 566: deux-millions-huit-cent-cinquante-sept-mille-cinq-cent-soixante-six*

However, depending on the sources, million and milliard are subject to that simplification or not. The "*Académie Française*" is recommending:

> *2 857 566: deux millions huit-cent-cinquante-sept-mille-cinq-cent-soixante-six*

Note that you do not use a comma in French to separate thousands, the comma is exclusively used as a decimal separator where English uses a dot.

Note also that while "*quatre-vingts*" takes an ending "*s*", there is no "*s*"  in "*quatre-vingt-dix-huit*" so your form is correct.

"*Cent nonante-huit mille*" is used instead of "*cent quatre-vingt-dix-huit mille*" in Belgium and Switzerland.

Finally, your last guess is also correct as "*million*" is a regular word so must take the plural form in "*deux millions* ..."

Comment: +1. One should keep in mind that the 1990 reformed orthography is far from being the most used one, at least in France. Most textbooks and many, if not most, teachers still use the pre-1990 rules. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_French_orthography#Application and http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990#Oppositions.

Comment: So the "et" only apply in the case of un?

Comment: It is used for 21 (*vingt-et-un*) up to 61 (*soixante-et-un*), and also 61 to 91 where *septante-et-un*, *huitante-et-un* and *nonante-et-un* are used. On the other hand, 101 and 1001 do not use "un", i.e. are written *cent un*, *mille un* and so on.

Comment: On 70/80/90 in Belgium and France: *septante* and *nonante* are the prevalent forms in both countries. *Huitante* is used only in Switzerland, but is more frequent in some "cantons" than others. *Octante* is, contrary to a widespread belief, not used anymore (see https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/03/26/comment-dit-on-80-en-belgique-et-en-suisse/).

Comment: @Greg Oui, je suis bien au courant. Je suis même partisan d'une promotion de l'usage de septante, huitante et nonante dans toute la francophonie. Il est quand même ridicule que la France, souvent dite cartésienne, se traîne une telle casserole qui perturbe l'apprentissage du français.

Comment: @jiliagre: le danois a réussi a faire encore plus compliqué: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danois#Nombres

Comment: @Greg "50 est la moitié du 3e fois 20", je plains les petits danois...

Comment: @Greg Dans le même ordre d'idée, le catalan a un système horaire intéressant: *dos quarts menys cinc de sis*, littéralement « deux quarts moins cinq de six » qui signifie « cinq heure vingt-cinq » !